# How can I get a custom UIControl to participate in a segue as a push action?

Tags: iphone, xcode, interface-builder, uistoryboard, segue

I have a custom class that inherits from UIControl, to get touch events. It's basically a collection of other controls that acts as one. I'm converting my app from xibs to a storyboard. It's been mostly painless, except for this.

I drag a UIView into my scene, change the class to my custom control, hook it up to outlets on my ViewController. What I want to do with the control when it's clicked is perform a (push) segue to another ViewController. But the outlets in the designer aren't there for my UIControl to set up the segue.

Is it possible to do this? If so, what do I do to the class to enable that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't think so. Looking at the Connections Inspector pane, `UIButton` and `UIBarButtonItem` instances get special treatment—an extra "triggered segues" action you can connect to adjacent view controllers:

[image: UIButtons can trigger segues]

While changing your view's class to a descendent of `UIControl` makes the standard suite of control events available, unfortunately Interface Builder does not let you hook up a segue. The best you can do is create a manually-triggered segue from your view controller to another, then connect your custom control to an `IBAction` method that performs the segue programmatically:

```
- (IBAction)performManualSegue:(XYZCustomControl *)sender
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"manualPushSegue" sender:sender];
}
```

[image: IBAction for manually triggering segue]